# "Role elevation" for already logged-in user with "FOSUser Bundle" without logging out first

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using the FOSUser bundle to manage access for a data export bundle that I created for my collegue on top of a bigger Symfony project of our company.
Therefore I created a DataexportBundle that enables exporting defined parts of data from the Symfony project.

The DataexportBundle offers

- a download area for our employees where they can select a query and
  get the data in different formats like json or csv.
- an admin area where the database queries that are selectable in the
  employees' download area can be managed (added, edited and deleted).

The "Data Export" download area must be protected so that only employees are able to access it. Anonymous users are not allowed to access this area.
The "Data Export" admin area shall be only accessed by some employees that have an additional admin role.

Therefore, I enabled a role hierarchy in my "security.yml" file:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:        [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_EDITORIAL:   [ROLE_USER, ROLE_EDITORIAL]
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_EDITORIAL, ROLE_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/dataexport/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/dataexportadmin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/dataexport/, role: ROLE_EDITORIAL }
        - { path: ^/dataexportadmin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    firewalls:
        admin_secured:
            context: site
            pattern: ^/dataexportadmin/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                target_path_parameter: redirect_url
                login_path: /dataexportadmin/login
                check_path: /dataexportadmin/login_check
            logout:
                path:   /dataexportadmin/logout
            anonymous: true
        main:
            context: site
            pattern: ^/dataexport/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                target_path_parameter: redirect_url
                default_target_path: /dataexport/
                login_path: /dataexport/login
                check_path: /dataexport/login_check
            logout:
                path:  /dataexport/logout
            anonymous: true
```

As you can see, I also defined two firewalls. By doing so, I want to achive that an already logged-in user with "ROLE_EDITORIAL" role (having no "ROLE_ADMIN" role) gets shown a login form where he can login as another user (who must have the "ROLE_ADMIN" role set).

I created 2 users:

```
sudo -u www-data bin/console fos:user:create employee_A
sudo -u www-data bin/console fos:user:promote employee_A ROLE_EDITORIAL

sudo -u www-data bin/console fos:user:create employee_B
sudo -u www-data bin/console fos:user:promote employee_B ROLE_ADMIN
```

My problem is that this kind of "privilege elevation" does not work; Instead, a "403 Forbidden" page is shown when "employee_A" clicks a link to the "Data Export" admin area. My plan is to show a login form here instead. If login (and hereby "privilege elevation") fails, the role "ROLE_EDITORIAL" of the curently logged-in user "employee_A" must be kept.
I know that a more usual way would be that user employee_A (ROLE_EDITORIAL) logs out first and after that, logs in as user employee_B (ROLE_ADMIN). This way, the bundle already works, but I'd like to implement a kind of "privilege elevation" like I said.

My question is: How can "privilege elevation" be done with "FOSUser bundle", or any other Symfony user management bundle?

File "config.yml":

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\FosUser
    from_email:
        address: ...
        sender_name: ...
```

File "routing.yml":

```
dataexportadmin_login:
    path:  /dataexportadmin/login
    defaults: { _controller: MyUserBundle:Security:login }

dataexportadmin_login_check:
    path:  /dataexportadmin/login_check
    defaults: { _controller: MyUserBundle:Security:check }

dataexportadmin_logout:
    path:  /dataexportadmin/logout
    defaults: { _controller: MyUserBundle:Security:logout }

dataexport_login:
    path:  /dataexport/login
    defaults: { _controller: MyUserBundle:Security:login }

dataexport_login_check:
    path:  /dataexport/login_check
    defaults: { _controller: MyUserBundle:Security:check }

dataexport_logout:
    path:  /dataexport/logout
    defaults: { _controller: MyUserBundle:Security:logout }

dataexport_admin:
    resource: "@DataexportBundle/Controller/QueryController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /dataexportadmin
    options:
        expose: true

dataexport:
    resource: "@DataexportBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /dataexport
    options:
        expose: true

my_user:
    resource: "@MyUserBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

File "My/UserBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php"

```
<?php

namespace My\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;

class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
    public function renderLogin(array $data)
    {
        $requestAttributes = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();

        if ($requestAttributes->get('_route') === 'dataexportadmin_login')
        {
            $template = sprintf('MyUserBundle:Security:adminlogin.html.twig');
        }
        else
        {
            $template = sprintf('MyUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig');
        }

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse($template, $data);
    }
}
```

The relevant difference between the two Twig templates is the "action" attribute of the form tag:

```
<form action="{{ path("dataexport_login_check") }}" method="post">
```

vs.

```
<form action="{{ path("dataexportadmin_login_check") }}" method="post">
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Using FOS User Bundle only a user is whether authenticated or it is not.
If you login another user you will change the logged in user.

You may want to change your security on `dataexportadmin` :

1. lower the access_control level
2. Route your form to a action in you Bundle
3. If credentials checks, set an expiration date in `$_SESSION['allowd_to_dataexportadmin_until']`
4. In your export bundle dispatch an event on everyaction to check if current user has either a role among AUTHORISED_ROLES (admin) or a not null `$_SESSION['allowd_to_dataexportadmin_until']` and lower than `new \DateTime()`

Hope this helps